# Java overloading with different alignment of parameters

Tags: java

```
public void giveInput(String x, int y) {
        System.out.print("X parameters"+x+"Y parameters"+y);
    }

    public void giveInput(int y, String x) {
        System.out.print("x parameters"+x+"Y parameters"+y);
    }
```

why does alignment of parameters doesn't matter in overloading. It compiles well

Comment: Part of it could be that your parameters all use different variable types.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect this to compile?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to compile because the parameters are the same but in the different order.

Answer (score 6):

<s>Alignment</s> Order of parameters *does* matter, which is why what you have compiles. It compiles because there's no ambiguity, `giveInput("", 0)` is clearly distinct from `giveInput(0, "")`. They could well do entirely different things.

All Java cares about is that the signature of the method uniquely identify it. The signature (for the purposes of overloading) is the method name and the types of its formal parameters, in order. From [JLS§8.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> When a method is invoked ([§15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)), the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked ([§15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)).

It's worth noting that the *names* of the formal parameters are *not* significant, `giveInput(String x, int y)` would conflict with `giveInput(String foo, int bar)`, because names are irrelevant, it's the order and types that matter.

Answer (score 5):

These are two different methods with different signatures. The order of the argument types in a method is part of the method's signature in Java. The names of the arguments, on the other hand, don't matter.

Since the argument names don't matter, your code is equivalent to :

```
public void giveInput(String x, int y) {
    System.out.print("X parameters"+x+"Y parameters"+y);
}

public void giveInput(int a, String b) {
    System.out.print("x parameters"+b+"Y parameters"+a);
}
```

On the other hand, these two methods have the same signature, and therefore will result in compilation error :

```
public void giveInput(String x, int y) {
    System.out.print("X parameters"+x+"Y parameters"+y);
}

public void giveInput(String a, int b) {
    System.out.print("x parameters"+b+"Y parameters"+a);
}
```